# Raw Qt WebEngine renders a black screen yet works with QtQuick

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, qt5, qt5.6, qwebengineview

I'm writing a simple QT application which uses a QWebEngineView to render a simple web page. If I use QtQuick then the page loads and renders properly. However, our current environment precludes me from using QtQuick so I tried using QWebEngineView directly, i.e. attaching it to a simple widget and it fails miserably, producing a completely black screen.

When I set the QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING environment variable and attach a chromium browser to the port, the page seems to have loaded correctly so it just looks like it's a rendering issue.

I suspect I need to set up the environment or application in some way that QtQuick does but I'm not sure what is required. As far as I can tell, I'm using OpenGL ES 3.0 to render (or at least QtQuick uses it, I'm not 100% sure that a manually instantiated QWebEngineView is using it.. Maybe that's the issue )

I throw myself on your collective wisdom...

Comment: I think, from a bit of digging, that QtQuick seems to use a QWebView instead of a QWebEngineView. Does anyone know if I can use a QWebView in my non QtQuick app.

Comment: provide a [mcve] :)

Comment: If you knew QT you'd know that minimal just doesn't apply.

Comment: Hahaha, I do not know Qt. :)

Comment: I suggest checking if QtQuick sets up a default rendering environment with depth buffering and/or adjusts the viewpoint. Two very common reasons for a black screen is looking the wrong way and drawing everything in black

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I'll investigate this.